# Ionic AES256 - PHP AES-256-CBC

Tags: php, ionic-framework, encryption, aes

Im trying to generate a message cyphred in the official Ionic library '[AES256](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/aes256/)' and decypt it in my PHP server.

The app send the IV via URL to server and the server knows the key already, then the server try to decrypt the message and sends back the decripted one.

Server side recives `.../api/users.json?apikey=1234567890123456&encdata=zx6Jyh8nfunTvN7+TKG34g==`:

```
    $key = hex2bin('96955281571734888210331492195226');

    echo "key: ".bin2hex($key).", encdata: ".$_GET['encdata'].", apikey: ".$_GET['apikey'];
    $out = openssl_decrypt($_GET['encdata'], 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $_GET['apikey']);
    $out = bin2hex($out);
    fwrite($log, $out);

    echo json_encode($out);
```

Client side generates:

```
this.encrypt(this.secureKey, this.secureIV, data).then((encdata) => {

    console.log('HTTP request - Sending: '+ url + '&encdata=' + encdata.toString());
    this.http.get(url + '&encdata=' + encdata).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(encdataserver => {
      console.log('HTTP request - Received: '+JSON.stringify(encdataserver));

      this.decrypt(this.secureKey, this.secureServerPreKey, encdataserver).then((data)=>{      
        resolve(data);
      })

    });

  })
```

I totally stranded so ANY help is very very welcome.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Why does your `encrypt` method call `decrypt`?

Comment: When ionic sends the encrypted data, php decrypt this and sends encrypted(not yet) back to ionic, then ionic decrypts this result.

Comment: Right. And the error is?

Comment: There is no error, just the decrypted string is not the start string.

Comment: hello @MoustachedMonkey any progress in this ?? i am encrypted with ionic 3 aes256 i just want to decrypted with php

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you performing any base 64 decoding, while the ciphertext pretty clearly is base 64 encoded.

Furthermore, Ionic clearly specifies that PKCS#7 padding was used for the ciphertext, while you are specifying zero padding, so the padding schemes don't match.

Note that AES in itself is not a transport mechanism. If you simply encrypt / decrypt this way, an attacker may use a padding oracle attack and if that succeeds the confidentiality of the message is lost.